# Unable to throw exception from "convertToDatabaseColumn" while using converter

Tags: java, spring, jpa, exception

I am making a converter for a class and it includes parsing a JSON. I want to throw the exception if the json parsing fails but it is only allowing me to try/catch the exception. I need to throw the exception to the upper layers in order to propagate the error. I tried adding throws at the function but it says that it is not allowed. Is there any way to propagate the exception to the upper layers?

```
    @Converter( autoApply = true)
    public static class classConverter implements AttributeConverter<Class, String> {
        
        @Override
        public String convertToDatabaseColumn(Class classobj) {
                        
            ObjectMapper object = new ObjectMapper();
            String json = new String();

                try {
                    json = object.writeValueAsString(classobj);
                } catch (JsonProcessingException e) {
                    // Gives error when i try to throw the error
                    throw e;

                }

            
            return json;
            
        }
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can wrap it into a sub class  of `RuntimeExcpetion`.

Declare a new `RuntimeException`:

```
public class JsonProcessingRuntimeException extends RuntimeExcpetion{
}
```

and throw it in  your class:

```
} catch (JsonProcessingException e) {
    // Gives error when i try to throw the error
    throw new JsonProcessingRuntimeException (e);

}
```

And in upper layer you can catch the `JsonProcessingRuntimeException`.

Comment: It worked. But i am a bit curious about why do we have to throw a runtime exception instead of a standerd exception? @Jens

Comment: @RahulMishra What you called *standerd exception* is known as *checked exceptions* this must be declared in the method signature. If it is not done, you can not throw it. *RuntimeException must not be declared and can be thrown at every position